# How to Share Variables Value Between two Running Android Applications

Tags: android, variables, global-variables

I have a first Android application, running in background (as service). A second application is running at the same time, which has a GUI. Now I want some information to be passed from my first application to my second application.

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another possibility is to use shared memory (i.e. Android "ashmem"):

- http://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Features
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html

Answer (score 2):

use Content Provider for the same. See
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/41133/1954

Comment: you mean , using Content Provider, will i be able to direct access the variable value of another application ?

Comment: no, by content provider you would need to define the interfaces, you want to open accross applications.

Comment: and one more thing, if both applications(Ui and background app) may be part of single application, then service may access your UI app data as well, without declaring any Content Provider

Comment: If you want to start a particular activity on a particular event you can use intent-filter, also.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Data you are sharing either Primitive type or Persistent Data or Non-Persistent Data.

If **Primitive data** - use Intent.putExtras().

**Non-Persistent Objects** -

1. Singleton class
2. A public static field/method
3. A HashMap of WeakReferences to Objects

**Persistent Objects** :

1. Application Preferences
2. Files
3. ContentProviders

4.SQLite DB

Check this [Developer guide for Further reference](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html).